# From synopsys vcs, how to separate compile and elaboration step? (to run a elaboration from pre-compiled library)

Tags: compilation, version-control, elaboration

From synopys VCS, I'd like to run multiple simulations from single compiled library, by changing parameter (for the purpose of conditional generate) for each run.

Because parameter override is done during elaboration stage, so I expect to save disk space and compile time if each run can share single complied library.

So, the expected procedure change will be from (all run are done from different dir)

```
Run 1: compile -> elab -> sim
Run 2: compile -> elab -> sim
Run 3: compile -> elab -> sim
…
```

To

```
Precompile to worklib
Run 1: {worklib} -> elab -> sim
Run 2: {worklib} -> elab -> sim
Run 3: {worklib} -> elab -> sim
…
```

Previously, I used Cadence incisive and xcellium, which they support single step procedure for this, like ncvlog, ncelab and ncsim (or xvlog, xelab and xsim).
First I think the step can be break-down which vcs may support.

1. Compile and export compiled library (i.e. worklib)
2. Elaboration and simulation from compiled library (worklib) with parameter overriding (not a define, because the hierarchy can be newly defined based on parameter setting)

So, hope to have a simple command example for each stage.
Thanks.